# Finding ways to move from one point to another.

Tags: combinatorics

We have a map as shown here:

[image]

The goal is to go from the [Start] to the [Fin] while avoiding the [X] and pass through all the [O] tiles.

We have 6 steps in total, we can move one tile each step and in 4 directions (no diagonal moves). It's allowed to visit a tile more than once.

So in how many ways can we reach the [Fin] in exact 6 steps while satisfy the conditions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried a smaller version of the problem to try out some counting strategies?

Comment: If you are required to use exactly $(15)$ moves, then the task is impossible, because it can only be done by using an *even* number of moves.  To see this, note that the *direct* path involves $(4)$ moves down and $(4)$ moves to the right.  Each *indirect* move (i.e. moving to the left or up) must add $(2)$ moves to the total journey.  Therefore, you can never finish after an *odd* number of moves.

Comment: @AnotherUser I have no idea what I should do tbh. This problem just pop up in my head and I wonder If it can be solved by somehow.

Comment: @AHusain I tried some similar problems but with restricted movement (only moving East and South). I just wonder how to solve it if we can move freely in all 4 directions.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for your reply, I think that it's not required to use all 15 moves. So in how many ways can we solve this problem in less than 15 moves?

Comment: As other comments have indicated, you need to show work to get someone to respond.  See [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for details.  Note particularly, the **Edit Tools** section, and the section on specifying the source of the problem.  If all else fails, you could edit your posting to show work by using brute force on a smaller version of the problem, and looking for patterns in the solution to the smaller version.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, you could include your attempt to integrate these patterns into the larger problem.  For what it's worth, in the larger problem, you could partition the set of all solutions into the subsets that use exactly $k$ moves, where $k \in \{8,10,12,14\}.$

Comment: Are you allowed to visit a square more than once?

Comment: @2661923 Oh...I see. Ok. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @paw88789 yes it's allowed to visit a square more than once.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for your advice. I have literally no idea how to solve this problem. though, I have little knowledge of math. I've tried some simple methods such as Pascal's triangle but to no avail. I've edited the problem to a smaller version as you suggested. Hope it can help.

Comment: There's fewer than 20 paths in total which use only 6 steps. Can you write down all of them? (Write down a sequence like DDRUDR for 'down, down, right, up, down, up', or number the squares 1-9 in reading order and write a sequence like 1478589' for 'visit square 1, then square 4, then square 4, then square 8, then square 5, then square 8, then square 9').

Comment: Are you familiar with graphs and counting walks on them?

Comment: @ploosu2 It sounds new to me, maybe I'll spend some time learning about it.

Comment: @1Rock Thanks for your comment, here's the list of paths that I've counted so far. I might miss some though:

DDRUDR DDRURD DDRLRR/

DDUDRR DDURRD/

DRDURD DRDUDR DRDLRR/

DRRLRD DRRLDR/

DRUDDR DRUDRD/

DRLRRD DRLDRR DRLRDR/

RDDLRR RDDUDR RDDURD/

RDRLRD RDRLDR/

RDLRRD RDLDRR RDLRDR/

RDUDRD RDUDDR/

DUDDRR DUDRRD DUDRDR/

RLRDDR RLRDRD

Comment: Since you changed the map in such a way that the comments are no longer accurate, could you include the previous map or indicate that the earlier version of the question had a bigger map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to count the walks from Start to Fin on the graph where the vertices are the squares (except the one marked with X) and there's an edge between two vertices if the squares are adjacent. First, count all walks from Start to Fin (forget that we want the walk to visit all O-squares). Then subtract the number of walks that don't visit the middle square, and subtract the number of walks that don't visit the bottom left square. Now according to inclusion-exclusion we would have to add back the number of walks that visit neither of the O-squares but such walks don't exist: to go from Start to Fin, you must cross the diagonal.

To count the walks not visiting a square, simply remove that square from the graph and count walks on the resulting graph. (As you can see if we remove both O-squares, the graph becomes disconnected and there isn't a path from Start to Fin.)

The number of walks of length $n$ between two vertices $s$ and $t$ on a graph can be calculated as the $s, t$-entry of the $n$th power of the adjacency matrix of the graph: $(A^n)_{s,t}$ (matrix indexed by the vertices).

[image: the graphs g, g1 and g2]

Let $G$ be the full graph, $G_1$ the graph with the middle square deleted and $G_2$ the graph with bottom-left deleted. And let their adjacency matrices be $A, A_1$ and $A_2$ accordingly. We have (vertices are indexed in the order `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)`).

$$
\displaystyle A= \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right),  \\
A_1 = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right),
A_2 = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

The solution is

$$(A^n)_{1,8} - (A_1)^n_{1,7} - (A_2)^n_{1,7}.$$

By diagonalizing the matrices (we're lucky here the eigenvalues can be solved algebraically and the eigenvector matrix and its inverse aren't that bad) we can find the "nice" formula which works for $n$ even (for odd $n$ the answer is $0$ as mentioned in the comments)

$$\frac{5+\sqrt{10}}{60}\left(4+\sqrt{10}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}+\frac{5-\sqrt{10}}{60}\left(4-\sqrt{10}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}+\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)-6^{\frac{n}{2}-1}+2^{\frac{n}{2}-1}.$$